Using MUXs to Address Multiple Devices
I am fairly new to I2C and coding in general as I am currently majoring in electrical engineering. I needed to design a board with multiple MUXs, I am using TCA9548As, that can address interchangeable devices. I have my board built already, I have 4 MUXs and 32 screw terminals for the slave devices. Does anyone have any advice on where I can find resources to help write the code for it? I found adafruit's library for the TCA9548A, but I can't find anything on all the definitions for all the commands. It needs to be in python and the board is built to work with raspberry Pi or direct input cables for master power and I2C input. Thank you.

The data sheet has the only description you or anyone else needs to write a fully working system. Have you read it, and if yes, what part needs explaining? They are not "commands", simply a bit sets if chanel is selected or not.

I have looked at bits and pieces a few times, mainly when I was designing my PCB. However, I'll read through it again now that I'm done with my PCB design and doing the firmware.

After reading the datasheet I think I know what I need to do. If I am correct this should be the format of my code: Import the write libraries needed, create the bus, set the 4 TCA9548As to their proper address, scan for what slave devices are connected to the 8 channels of the first MUX, then the 2nd MUX, then the 3rd, then 4th, then send a start bit to the slave device and its address, send a write bit, wait for acknowledge, send the data, stop the transaction, and loop all of that until I have transferred data to all the devices that were scanned as connected?

Sounds like you already know what to do. I don't know in which language you will do this, what "libraries" you would even need for doing I2C in that language, what would "creating the bus" even mean (maybe some object-oriented language?), the muxes would already be at their hardware-set addresses, and all you need to do is to select one or multiple buses behind the mux or multiple muxes, and communicate as usual with any chip you want. Just bear in mind that it may be difficult or impossible to scan what chips are present, unless only chip of type X are in specific addresses for that type.

So to aswer the question, the best resource how to program that chip is the data sheet.
Failing that, it is a very common chip so likely some hobbyists have created blogs or Youtube videos about it, if you are into that sort of things.
You can also read the source code of the libraries for that chip, I believe at least there are Arduino and Python libraries, but it does not matter, they all do the same basic thing regardless of the language.
The TCA9548 is almost the same (but slightly improved) as the original PCA9548 so you may find more search results with that
All you need to do for each mux is to send one data byte to it which controls which buses are currently connected. And that data byte is also readable.
There are scenarios where you don't want to enable more than one bus at a time in order to not put too much pull-up resistances or too much bus capacitance in total to the host bus.
In some scenarios you may want to control the reset pin of the muxes; individually or just all commoned.
The rest what you want to do with the buses behind the muxes is up to you.
It might not be easy to detect if there are chips present or not, unless you know the chips, their addresses and their quirks. Many people ask why scanning the I2C address space does not show any chips and the answer is, different chips react differently to different operations performed on it, and so finding a chip depends on which method you use to detect them. Some chips will not respond to an unsolicited read unless you wrote a correct register address first and then continue with a repeated start condition instead of a stop conditon.

Amazing, thank you so much for all the help, this gives me a great launch pad to further my work on my project, I very much appreciate it.
